# Куда ставить ударение в слове лилея?

Tags: орфоэпия

«Как лилея глядится в нагорный ручей, ты стояла над первою песней моей.» Фет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из [**Нацкорпуса:**](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=poetic&sort=gr_tagging&ext=10&req=%EA%E0%EA%20%EB%E8%EB%E5%FF%20%E3%EB%FF%E4%E8%F2%F1%FF)

> *Как лилѐя глядѝтся в наго̀рный ручѐй,*
>
> *Ты стоя̀ла над пѐрвою пѐсней моѐй,*
>
> *И была̀ ли при э̀том побѐда, и чья̀, ―*
>
> *У ручья̀ ль от цветка̀, у цветка̀ ль от ручья̀?*
>
> [А. А. Фет. Alter ego (1878.01.00)]

Comment: Стал сам искать, но не могу понять как включить показ ударений? http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=poetic&sort=gr_tagging&ext=10&nodia=1&req=%EB%E8%EB%E5%FF+%E3%EB%FF%E4%E8%F2%F1%FF

Comment: Нажмите далее на _"версия с ударениями"_ (в правом верхнем углу экрана).